# Why Google Swiffy does not support audio in Mozilla Firefox?

Tags: google-swiffy

I wanted to convert some few flash files to HTML 5 Based Videos, I tried using Google Swiffy which was much better than any other converters. The only problem is it doesn't have support for audio in Mozilla Firefox, android Browsers and Mobile safari browsers. Is there any way to manipulate the JSON data and make it work on all the browsers, if yes, how? if no, why?. 
Clear explanation on how Swiffy works is much appreciated.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

I've found that a better solution is to separate the audio and animation and encapsulate each.  For example, create an AnimationPlayer and an AudioPlayer.  Within each of those, implement Swiffy and say Jplayer respectively.  This way if you need to replace your swiffy animations with CreateJS sprites or whatever the next cool thing is, you can without breaking your other code.  This also of course addresses the audio problem by using a well developed audio player that likely works and is maintained for all browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Since the question was asked, the audio now works in Firefox (23) - the compatibility chart at the swiffy site stops at FF 15. Let's say "partially supported", because in both FF and IE9, the sound is apt to stop when animations get complicated. Works beautifully in Chrome, though.

Michael Prdescott's answer may offer some hope for iPads, which still don't recognize swiffy sound. But, I'm wondering how it would work - the user would press two buttons (one for sound, one for video)? Or the audio and video would load together and autoplay? Either way, wouldn't that make a mess (or at least be risky) when sound/video are meant to be synchronized?